# How do I put XML into a List of Dictionaries with C# on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, .net, xml, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

Here is the XML I have in a file:

**SPECIAL NOTE:
This is a question for Windows Phone 7, not general C#**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <item>
        <date>01/01</date>
        <word>aberrant</word>
        <def>straying from the right or normal way</def>
    </item>

    <item>
        <date>01/02</date>
        <word>Zeitgeist</word>
        <def>the spirit of the time.</def>
    </item>
</rss>
```

I need it in a `List` (aka array) of `Dictionary` objects. Each `Dictionary` represents an `<item>`. Each element like `<word>` is the `key` with type `string` and each value like "Zeitgeist" is the `value` with type `string`.

Is there any easy way to do this? I'm coming from Objective-C and iOS so this is completely new to me with .NET and C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ-to-XML makes it pretty easy.  Here's a complete example:

```
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = @"
<rss version='2.0'>
    <item>
        <date>01/01</date>
        <word>aberrant</word>
        <def>straying from the right or normal way</def>
    </item>

    <item>
        <date>01/02</date>
        <word>Zeitgeist</word>
        <def>the spirit of the time.</def>
    </item>
</rss>";
            var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            var result = xdoc.Root.Elements("item")
                .Select(itemElem => itemElem.Elements().ToDictionary(e => e.Name.LocalName, e => e.Value))
                .ToList();

        }
```

Instead of loading from a string with XDocument.Parse(), you would probably do XDocument.Load(filename) but either way you get an XDocument object to work with (I did a string just for example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq-Xml to do this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml); //xml is a String with your XML in it.
doc
.Root                         //Elements under the root element.
.Elements("item")             //Select the elements called "item".
.Select(                      //Projecting each item element to something new.
    item =>                   //Selecting each element in the item.
        item                  //And creating a new dictionary using the element name
        .Elements()           // as the key and element value as the value. 
        .ToDictionary(xe => xe.Name.LocalName, xe => xe.Value))
.ToList();
```

Comment: How do I add Linq to my project? Adding using System.Xml.Linq gives me an error saying that it's not in the assembly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You will need a reference to System.Xml.Linq. I'm not sure if this is possible with WP7.

Comment: Yea, I am trying to do it on Windows Phone 7.

Comment: I don't have the SDK, but a quick google seems to suggest it's possible. Right click your Project in Solution Explorer and click "Add Reference...". Click the ".Net" tab and look for System.Xml.Linq.

Comment: Fixed it... forgot to add a reference to the assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an easy way, it's called LINQ to XML.

Some resources:

[Parsing complex XML with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272164/parsing-complex-xml-with-c-sharp)

[LINQ to read XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/670563/linq-to-read-xml)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

Hope this helps...